# Mobile blazor bindings

Tags: xamarin.forms, blazor

Can I use .net standard 2.1 with the last Mobile blazor bindings  -Version 0.5.50-preview?  I also want to use Xamarin forms 5 in the project.  Is it possible to use Mobile blazor bindings with the Xamarin Forms 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could.

To get started, all you need is the [.NET Core 3.0 or 3.1 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download), Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac, and the ASP.NET and web development and Mobile development with .NET (Xamarin.Forms) workloads installed.

Install the templates by running this command from a command/shell window:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.MobileBlazorBindings.Templates::0.5.50-preview
```

And then create your first project by running this command:

```
dotnet new mobileblazorbindings -o FirstMobileBlazorBindingsApp
```

Open the solution (SLN file) in Visual Studio and mark either the Android or iOS project as the StartUp Project.

The more you could refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/walkthroughs/build-first-app).